# ActiveMQ Artemis can't get queue stat

Tags: activemq-artemis

There is a command of ./artemis that should display the statistics of queues : `./artemis queue stat` (the last one):

```
The most commonly used artemis commands are:
    address     Address tools group (create|delete|update|show) (example ./artemis address create)
    browser     It will browse messages on an instance
    consumer    It will consume messages from an instance
    create      creates a new broker instance
    data        data tools group (print) (example ./artemis data print)
    help        Display help information
    mask        mask a password and print it out
    migrate1x   Migrates the configuration of a 1.x Artemis Broker
    producer    It will send messages to an instance
    queue       Queue tools group (create|delete|update|stat|purge) (example ./artemis queue create)
```

However, when I try to use it `./artemis queue stat --user=master --password=master --url=tcp://0.0.0.0:1616`, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219014: Timed out after waiting 30,000 ms for response when sending packet -12]
```

The ActiveMQ Artemis broker is running on remote machine on port 1616.

The attempt of creating queue by these commands was successful, but I also failed to purge queue by this way.

Is there any ideas of what going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the broker is running on a different machine than the one where you're running the `queue stat` command then the url `tcp://0.0.0.0:1616` will *not* work. The address `0.0.0.0` is a special meta-address which is only really useful for a process which is *receiving* network connections (i.e. acting as a server). This address allows the server to receive connections on *all* network interfaces. It will not function correctly on a client. You can [read more about `0.0.0.0` here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, after changing 0.0.0.0 to localhost it begins to work! I also have another question-note (if it is necessary i will edit my main question) : am I right that firstly i  should stop all consumers/producers of queue first to purge this queue?

Comment: Please add a new question for the queue purge situation. Thanks!